# Github-flavored markdown not being applied as expected

Tags: eclipse, firefox, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I am writing some documentation using markdown files.  (*.md)  I am using the Markdown Editor version 1.2.0.201501260515 plugin for Eclipse.  I am also using the GFM Viewer feature Version 1.9.3 plugin to view the md files in Eclipse after I save them.  They look fine there.

I find that line breaks inside 'fenced code blocks' are not being formatted as expected when viewed in a Web Browser.

For example, here is a fragment from an md file

````
```
apply plugin: 'vt.platformwar.rpm'  
defaultTasks 'rpm'  
```
````

Yet, here is how this winds up being formatted in Firefox, after being deployed on a corporate Atlassian system that looks exactly like GitHub, but is not GitHub.

[image]

I tried viewing the same page in IE, and it blows up with a 500 Error.

I know very little about this technology never having used it before.  My source for how to format this was this: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-and-highlighting-code-blocks/

Why isn't this formattting correctly?  And is there a better way to do this kind of formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yet, here is how this winds up being formatted in Firefox, after being deployed on a corporate Atlassian system that looks exactly like GitHub, but is not GitHub.

Atlassian is most certainly not GitHub (a competitor actually) and many GitHub features are specific to GitHub. In fact, fenced-code-blocks are **not** a [standard Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) feature. While they existed before GitHub adopted them (although in a slightly different form) GitHub popularized the feature and many other Markdown implementations have since adopted it. However, for many implementations the feature is off by default. If you would like to use the feature you need to determine which Markdown implementation you are using and whether is has support for fenced-code-blocks. If so, you will need to turn the feature on. If not,  you will need to switch to using [standard Markdown code blocks](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode) by indenting your code blocks by at least 4 spaces or one tab:

```
Some standard Markdown text followed by a code block:

    apply plugin: 'vt.platformwar.rpm'
    defaultTasks 'rpm'
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Atlassian evidently doesn't support fenced code blocks.  I didn't know they were competitors of GitHub.

Comment: Yes, Atlassian is the company behind BitBucket, which is a competing service.